# Azure CI/CD not acknowledging project setting for Wix Toolset Setup Project

Tags: azure, azure-devops, wix

Azure Build not acknowledging `Wix project properties > Tool Settings > Compile > -arch x64`. The application still runs as a 32-bit application, even though locally it runs as 64-bit.

```
- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: Create  (PROD)
  inputs:
    solution: Setup.wixproj
    msbuildArchitecture: x64
    configuration: 'PROD'
    msbuildArguments: '/p:BuildProjectReferences=false'
```

[image]

**Update**

I'm getting the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Azure CI/CD not acknowledging project setting for Wix Toolset Setup Project

You could try to pass the adddiational parameter as msbuildArguments, like:

```
- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: Create  (PROD)
  inputs:
    solution: Setup.wixproj
    msbuildArchitecture: x64
    configuration: 'PROD'
    msbuildArguments: '/p:BuildProjectReferences=false /p:CompilerAdditionalOptions=-arch x64'
```

Comment: What about putting quotation marks on `"Setup.wixproj"`?